# When the application is deployed, the image does not appear

Tags: blazor-server-side, .net-6.0

I use this code to show image

```
<button type="submit" class="buttonstyle"><img src="/images/Logout.png" alt="Logout"></button>
```

Working fine on development machine .
But when I deployed to the server (Windows Server 2019) the folder is on partition C
I got this error

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
> (Not Found)

I try with this

> src="../wwwroot/images/Logout.png"

And I try to use a full path

```
<button type="submit" class="buttonstyle"><img src="@logoutImage" alt="Logout"></button>
@code{
    string? logoutImage = $@"{Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()}{@"\wwwroot\images\Logout.png"}";
}
```

I got this error

> Not allowed to load local resource: file:///C:/SmartHR/wwwroot/images/Logout.png

Update
[image]
Any Help .

Comment: Open your browser's developer tool (F12) and check the img src. Is it correct?

Comment: it shows /images/Logout.png

Comment: When I use the full path it shows src="C:\SmartHR\wwwroot\images\Logout.png"   with error Not allowed to load local resource: file:///C:/SmartHR/wwwroot/images/Logout.png

Comment: Are you sure the file actually exists on the server with that relative path? (We can't check your server, you must do that yourself).

Comment: Yes, it exists, I have added an image for the full path

Comment: Is the 'SmartHR' folder set up as the web root? and 'wwwrot' set up as 'content folder'?

Comment: Please let me know how I can accomplish this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading this article
[Host and deploy ASP.NET Core Blazor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/host-and-deploy/?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio)
I found this
Do not prefix links throughout the app with a forward slash. Either avoid the use of a path segment separator or use dot-slash (./) relative path notation:

❌ Incorrect: `<a href="/account">`
✔️ Correct: `<a href="account">`
✔️ Correct: `<a href="./account">`

After removing the forward slash from `<img src="images/Logout.png">`
Everything works fine.